Light radiation intensity equation
Is there an equation to convert Light radiation intensity from W/m² to Lux?
Note: The light source is the sun throughout the day (its intensity will vary over the day).

The conversion depends on the spectrum of the light source. Lux is  lumens per square meter, and lumens are supposed to measure how bright a light appears to human eyes. E.g., If you have one lamp that emits a certain number of Watts of red light, and you have another lamp that emits the same number of Watts of green light, then the green one will seem more bright. The green one emits more lumens.

Taking sun as the light source , the approximate conversion from irradiance(W/m^2) to illuminance(lux) is:
Illuminance(lux)=Irradiance(W/m^2)*683(lm/W)
Note:
The conversion factor 683(lm/W) is based on the maximum luminous efficacy of human vision under daylight ( photopic vision) at 555nm.
